# Support compile Visual Studio project (VB)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

please suport me to compile a old VB project.
We received a industrial equipment that uses a custom software created by the manufacturer (they gave us the Visual Basic project created in Visual Studio 7 years ago), the company had closed some time ago and we need to update the project. Every time i try to compile it i get errors.
How can identify what visual studio edition they used, what was the target framework, what solution platform .. i want to recreate the previous build settings.
I tried visual studio 2008 / 2019 /2022, .net 3.0 up to 4.5 , both x86 and 64. I do not know where to start.
The main issue is with the main form Main.vb because i get this errors

> Could not find type 'AxASMBSERIALLib.AxASMBSERIAL'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.
> Blockquote

> The variable 'AxM340Write' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
> Blockquote

But i do not have this .dll file. what i have is only "AxInterop.ASMBSERIALLib.dll and Interop.ASMBSERIALLib.dll"

kind regards

Comment: That error is from a COM library dependency that the project has ("COM" as in ActiveX/OLE-DB, don't confuse that with the "COM port")  - it's largely unrelated to the VS or .NET version.

Comment: It complains about a *type*, not an assembly.  Only you can see what types are exposed by the interop libraries, use Object Browser.

Comment: checked all referenced .dll files, none is referencing 'AxM340Write'

Comment: This project seems to rely on some COM components which are not present on this machine yet. You will have to dig further into the vendor materials and see if you can find out where the COM components are and how to register them on Windows. That goes far beyond Visual Studio and VB.NET, and is also vendor specific. You shouldn’t expect a concrete answer here, as that vendor does not sound like a well known one.

Comment: Assuming that this app is actually working on in some form (possibly in production) on a machine somewhere now.  Maybe you can troll that to find the required dll files?

Comment: Use `Notepad` to open the `.sln` file where you should see the Visual Studio version (assuming Visual Studio was used to create the solution/project). In the project folder, use Notepad to open the `.vbproj` file to see additional information about the project. In Visual Studio, select "Project" => "<project name> Properties" and look for the "Target Framework".

Comment: As already mentioned, you're missing a (32-Bit) COM aka "ActiveX" DLL. This has to be both on the PC you're trying to compile the app on and on all machines which are supposed to run the application. This DLL also needs to be registered _(regsvr32 dllname.dll)_ on each machine.

Comment: >Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010 Project("{911E67C6-3D85-4FCE-B560-20A9C3E3FF48}") > Blockquote and